# How to access a variable from another function without returning that variable in original function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to access a variable from a function within another function without returning that variable. I need to check if that variable is true or false then based on that running some other code... here what I am trying to do:

```
     function A() {
     var myVar = false;

     if (someValue) {
         switch (someOtherValue) {
             case 1:
                 myVar = true;
                 break;

             default:
                 something;
                 break;
         }
     }
    }


 function B() {
     // I need to call myVar here and get its last value;
     if (myVar) {
         .......
     }
 }
```

Note: I don't wanna pass any values to the functions or return any values. So, is it possible to get the myVar value.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: NO. You *can not* access a local variable from the outside. You have to somehow expose it. Either by making it a global variable or by returning it or passing it to some function, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `myVar` outside of both functions:

```js
var myVar;
    
function A(){
  myVar = false;
    
  var x = true;
  var y = 10;
  
  if (x) {
    switch (y){
      case 10:
        myVar = true;
        break;
      default:
        something;
        break;
    }
  }
}
    
function B() {
  // I need to call myVar here and get its last value;
  if(myVar){
    console.log("myVar is true");
  } else {
    console.log("myVar is false");     
  }
}
    
A();
B()
```

You do need to make sure that function `A` executes before function `B`.